# How to stop backtracking in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, backtracking

Suppose I am solving a problem (e.g. `N-Queen`) with *backtracking*. What if I want to find the only one (the 1-st) solution rather than all of them.

I guess I can do it *imperatively* (e.g. with a mutable boolean flag). I wonder how I can do it *functionally*.

Comment: Tell the function how many solutions you want.

Answer (score 14):

While Scala's `Option` will work here, as two other answers have pointed out, a more idiomatic functional approach would be to use a "lazy list"—or a [`Stream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html), in Scala—to represent the set of solutions.

I've found myself writing code like this, for example:

```
trait Node[A] {
  def children: Stream[A with Node[A]]

  def dfs(f: A => Boolean): Stream[A] = this.children.flatMap {
    child => if (f(child)) Stream(child) else child.dfs(f)
  }
}
```

Now suppose I have a `Board` class that extends `Node[Board]` and that has an implementation of the `children` method that returns all valid boards with one additional piece. Suppose it also has some other useful stuff, like a `size` method, a companion object with an `empty`, etc.

I can then write the following to get a `Stream` of solutions:

```
val solutions = Board.empty.dfs(_.size == 8)
```

A `Stream` is lazy and only evaluates its head, so right now we've only searched the tree far enough to find the first solution. We can get this solution using `head`:

```
scala> solutions.head
res1: Board = 
o . . . . . . .
. . . . o . . .
. . . . . . . o
. . . . . o . .
. . o . . . . .
. . . . . . o .
. o . . . . . .
. . . o . . . .
```

Or whatever. But I can also get other results if I want them:

```
scala> solutions(10)
res2: Board = 
. o . . . . . .
. . . . . . o .
. . . . o . . .
. . . . . . . o
o . . . . . . .
. . . o . . . .
. . . . . o . .
. . o . . . . .
```

This searches just enough more of the tree to find the tenth solution, and then stops.

The big advantage of `Stream` over the `Option` approach is that I can get additional results if I need them, without paying more for the first.

Comment: I'm speechless. Really great solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple case with a depth-first search that stops when it finds what it's looking for.  It makes use of `Option`, as mentioned in Chris K's answer.

```
case class Tree[A](v: A, subtrees: Tree[A]*) {
  def dfs(s: A): Option[A] = {
    println("visiting " + v)
    subtrees.foldLeft(if(v == s) Some(v) else None)((r, t) => 
      if(r.isDefined) 
        r 
      else 
        t.dfs(s)
    )
  }
  override def toString() = "Tree(%s%s%s)".format(v, if(subtrees.nonEmpty) ", " else "", subtrees.mkString(", "))
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> val t = Tree(1, Tree(2, Tree(3), Tree(4)), Tree(5, Tree(6), Tree(7)))
t: Tree[Int] = Tree(1, Tree(2, Tree(3), Tree(4)), Tree(5, Tree(6), Tree(7)))
```

The tree `t` looks like

```
     1
   /   \
  2     5
 / \   / \
3   4 6   7
```

So we can search for an element and trace the nodes it visits:

```
scala> t.dfs(6)
visiting 1
visiting 2
visiting 3
visiting 4
visiting 5
visiting 6
res42: Option[Int] = Some(6)
```

Notice that we don't visit any more nodes after we find what we're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using a recursive search function, your function should either return a result (i.e. positioning of the queens) or an indication that no result could be found for that branch.  Scala probably has an option/maybe type, you can use that.  This advice is equally applicable to any functional language.

Comment: Yes, Scala does have an [`Option[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option) type.  You use the subtypes `Some(value)` to indicate a value, or `None` to indicate no value.